# I have an Image View in a layout in android, how can i zoom it for a short time after clicking?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android programming. I only need to show to the user that he clicked on the image view by this short duration zooming. I need for this simple effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scale animation to make your target view bigger and then return it to normal size. Something like:

```
imageView.animate().scaleX(1.5f).scaleY(1.5f).withEndAction(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        imageView.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
    }

});
```